# Calculating the sum of the series $x^a+x^{a^2}+x^{a^3}+......$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$x^a+x^{a^2}+x^{a^3}+......$$

Is there a way to do it? Assume 0<a<1 and finite number of terms , say until 'n' terms.

Comment: @Integrand I have mentioned that i lies between o and 1, so it definetly belongs to real ig?....

Comment: Still use $a$ for that variable.  Easy edit, no?

Comment: Semantics aside, I don't think the sum in question has a closed-form.

Comment: I don’t think there’s an answer either, a keyword if you want to search google is ‘lacunary series’

Comment: Assuming $a$ is not close to $1$ and that $x$ is a reasonable number then $a^n$ approaches $0$ quickly and $x^{a^n}$ approaches $1$.

Comment: [Wikipedia speaks about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function).